# How do I convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to Date in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i'm working with firestore, and getting stuck when i get the timestamp from firestore. how i convert this `Timestamp(seconds=1556006384, nanoseconds=994000000)` to Date in kotlin.

my minimum SDK is 21 so the  code below doesn't work

```
val timestamp = it["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
val milliseconds = timestamp.seconds * 1000 + timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000
val tz = ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta (UTC+07:00)")
val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds), tz)
```

thank you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#plusNanos-long-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date-long-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using this code:

```
val timestamp = it["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
val milliseconds = timestamp.seconds * 1000 + timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
val netDate = Date(milliseconds)
val date = sdf.format(netDate).toString()
Log.d("TAG170", date)
```

Answer (score 14):

Call [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp.html#toDate()) on a Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object to return a Date object.

Comment: @wesleyfranks Calling a method on an object should be pretty straightforward.  Assuming your Timestamp object is in a val called "ts":  `ts.toDate()`

Answer (score 5):

Combined both answers on top and this is what worked for me.

```
val timestamp = data[TIMESTAMP] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
            val date = timestamp.toDate()
```

Answer (score -1):

> I used this class to serialize the Timestamp

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp

data class Article (
var createdAt: Timestamp? = Timestamp.now(),
var title: String = "",
var image: String = ""
)
```