# Add document to Firestore timestamp problem with gson

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, gson

When adding a document to Firestore null values are not skipped.
For this reason i tryed to serialize the object with gson.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .create()

return gson.fromJson(
    gson.toJson(this), object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}.type
)
```

This works fine expect for that i have a variable of type `Date` in my object. When adding the serialized object to my Firestore the date variable changes his type to `String`, but i require it to be of type timestamp. If i do not not serialize the object with json the type fits my requirements but all values, even if they are null, are included.

Comment: Try to use TimeStamp type Instead of date https://stackoverflow.com/a/55824586/10954249

Comment: @DeePanShu Timestamp serializes to nanoseconds and seconds. I need a timestamp in date format like 8. Jannuary 2021 11:38:21 UTC+1

Comment: I know you can change nano seconds and seconds to Long milliseconds and then you can convert it to Date OR you can also use toDate() https://stackoverflow.com/a/55824586/10954249

Comment: @DeePanShu that would help me if I would retrieve it from Firestore, but I need to send it to Firestore.

Comment: Just use Timestamp.now() or Date.now() to sent it to Firestore

Comment: Why not create a simple data class that implements Serializable?